# How to add filepicker to angularjs template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filepicker.io, angularjs-ng-include, filepicker

I have built an app where I need dynamically change templates.

```
<div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
```

I have two templates like `addtext.html` and `addmedia.html`. I dynnamically change it using angularjs. But in my `addmedia.html` template, I have filepicker's pick file widget.

```
<input type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="..." data-fp-mimetypes="*/*" data-fp-container="modal" onchange="save_url()">
```

The pick widget does not load in the template. Is there any way to get it to work?

Comment: Be sure to add reference to file picker js file

Comment: They have some updated documentation on using filepicker with angular: https://developers.filepicker.com/docs/support/integration/108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know much about filepicker.io, but as far as I understand, the problem is that widgets are constructed on page load. This means that when you switch templates, `filepicker` may not process them automatically, see [documentation](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/widgets/#widgets-programming):

> We'll automatically convert any widgets that you have on page load. However, if you want to create widgets once the page has loaded, you can... call `filepicker.constructWidget();` method.

So, I would suggest you a simple directive that just puts an `input` tag with `type=filepicker`, and then linking filepicker to it using before mentioned method, like this:

```
app.directive('myFilepicker', [function() {
    return {        
        transclude: true,
        restrict: "E",    
        template: '<input type="filepicker">',
        replace: 'true',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            filepicker.constructWidget(element);
        }
    };
}]);
```

and in your markup you can use it like this:

```
<my-filepicker data-fp-apikey="..." data-fp-mimetypes="*/*" data-fp-container="modal" onchange="save_url()"></my-filepicker>
```

See this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k33o1gqr/)**. I don't have filepicker.io API key, but I hope this would work.